# UIWebView canGoBack and canGoForward always return NO

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to load data directly into `UIWebView`:

```
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" 
          baseURL:nil];
```

The data is some html string contains some external links. I am trying to enable the back and forward buttons base on the `UIWebView` properties:

```
self.forwardBtn.enabled = self.webView.canGoForward;
self.backBtn.enabled = self.webView.canGoBack;
```

However, even after I clicked on different links in the web view after the initial load, the `webView.canGoForward` and `webView.canGoBack` are always returning `NO`.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think the problem is if I use loadData or loadHTMLString, and then I check the url of the request in the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"url=%@", [request URL]);
    return YES;
}
```

It seems like that url is empty. 
I think this is why there is no history for goBack when using loadData.

Answer (score 1):

Easy quick solution, drag and drop bar button items to the xib, set image and untick the Enabled box from the Attribute Inspector.

```
// WebViewController.h
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *goBack;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *goForward;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

// WebViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([ReachabilityTest networkConnected] == YES)
    {
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]]];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection!" message:@"Please, make sure you have internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    self.goBack.enabled = [self.webView canGoBack];
    self.goForward.enabled = [self.webView canGoForward];
}
```

Comment: Adding the code in webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is **loadHTMLString** doesn't add this html file to the hierarchy of transitions, even when you add some baseURL. So you need to use **loadRequest** for normal navigation on the page hierarchy.

```
let htmlFile = "file"
guard let localfilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: htmlFile, ofType: "html"),
        let url = URL(string: localfilePath) else { return }
view.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my code, i use this code for my custom webview. This is not the perfect answer to your question but it will help. Sorry for formatting :)

```
- (IBAction)backwordButton:(id)sender {
    [webViewOutlet goBack];}

- (IBAction)forwordButton:(id)sender {
    [webViewOutlet goForward];
}

- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender {
    [webViewOutlet stopLoading];
}

- (IBAction)refreshButton:(id)sender {
    [webViewOutlet reload];
}

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIImage *goBackImageChange = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browserBackInactive@2x.png"];
    [goback setBackgroundImage:goBackImageChange forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *goForwordImageChange = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browserForwardInactive@2x.png"];
    [goforowrd setBackgroundImage:goForwordImageChange forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSURL *urlToLoad = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] URLForKey:@"URLToLoad"]; 
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad];
    [webViewOutlet loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    BOOL ableToGoBack = [webViewOutlet canGoBack];
    BOOL ableToGoForword = [webViewOutlet canGoForward];

    if (ableToGoBack == YES) {
        UIImage *goBackImageChange = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browserBack@2x.png"];
        [goback setBackgroundImage:goBackImageChange forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        UIImage *goBackImageChange = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browserBackInactive@2x.png"];
        [goback setBackgroundImage:goBackImageChange forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (ableToGoForword == YES) {
        UIImage *goForwordImageChange = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browserForward@2x.png"];
        [goforowrd setBackgroundImage:goForwordImageChange forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }  else {
        UIImage *goForwordImageChange = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browserForwardInactive@2x.png"];
        [goforowrd setBackgroundImage:goForwordImageChange forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am using "[webView loadData]" which is causing the problem. Using "[webView loadRequest]" will always work.

Comment: You're not suppose to add the @2x in your code, only in your file name to tell xcode to rather fetch that file for retina displays. Just saying ;)