# UIWebView canGoBack stopped working suddenly when using POST request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am loading request like this `[resultsWebView loadRequest:searchRequest];` Then I do this

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if ([resultsWebView canGoBack]) {
        [goBackButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
    else {
        [goBackButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    if ([resultsWebView canGoForward]) {
        [goForwardButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
    else {
        [goForwardButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

`canGoBack` is always returning `NO`.
It was working earlier, but it has stopped working suddenly(I have not done any code changes). I don't know how is this possible? Not getting any success to resolve this. There is a question on stackoverflow [UIWebView canGoBack and canGoForward always return NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810412/uiwebview-cangoback-and-cangoforward-always-return-no). But it is different as the question author was using `loadData` and he resolved the problem using `loadRequest`. But I am already using `loadRequest`. And again, it was working earlier, but it has stopped working suddenly(I have not done any code changes). Help me.

Cause of issue:

```
params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"query=%@", searchTextField.text];
NSMutableURLRequest *searchRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/do/m/]];
[searchRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[searchRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

If I use the simple request like below, it works fine.

```
NSURLRequest *searchRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.example.com/do/m/?%@", params]] ];
```

Thanks

Comment: What does not work? Is it always returning `NO`?

Comment: Yes it is always returning No. Thanks. edited question as well.

Comment: I have found the cause, but do not know why is this happening. Updated my question with the cause.

Comment: I have to send POST request only. Anyone know to get that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that, if the URL is same in the consecutive POST requests for the `loadRequest` method then `canGoBack` does not work. It was working for simple GET requests because URLs were different.
 To fix this, I sent the consecutive POST requests with two URLs, which are different from `UIWebView` perspective but actually same from the server perspective. I am setting the different URLs alternatively for consecutive POST requests, by adding a question-mark(?).

https://www.example.com/do/m/

https://www.example.com/do/m/?

In this way the URLs become different for consecutive POST requests of `UIWebView` and `canGoBack` method works.

Still I donot whether it is a bug in `UIWebView` or we can not use consecutive POST requests with `UIWebView` to get the `canGoBack` method works.

Answer (score 0):

The request may be fail even though you can see the page successfully rendered in the web view, you also need to set those go back/forward logics to `– webView:didFailLoadWithError:`.

Comment: I have done that and also checked using breakpoints to check if request is failing. Request is not failing. Thanks anyways.